# Вылизать = убраться

Tags: этимология

Почему мы говорим"вылизать", имея в виду чистую уборку?

Answer (score 1):

"Вылизать" - не просто чисто убраться, но прочистить каждую щёлочку, каждый закуток, стереть любую пылинку и пятнышко. Вычистить каждый сантиметр, чтобы ни одной мелочи не пропустить. Большой тряпкой получается "грубая" уборка - мелочи пропускаются, габарит не тот. Так вот и получается, что вылизать - убраться с таким вниманием, как будто каждый кусочек вылизывался языком.

А именно ВЫЛИЗАТЬ, мне кажется, потому что животные вылизываются. Кошка моется - кажый волосок ровно лежит.

Comment: Мне понравилась естественность Вашего ответа.

Comment: А я думал от слова лиз, лыз- очищать. Сегодня такое слово в словаре талышского языка. Старое роськое слово. Напримет вылизать от шел, шыл(шелуха, скорлупа, корка)- тоже талышского, роського.

Comment: @Mado: Возражать не буду, возможно и так. Мой ответ - только предположение.